# Understanding strrchr function

Tags: php, string, strrchr

I'm doing some tests with function strrchr, but I can't understand the output:

```
$text = 'This is my code';
echo strrchr($text, 'my');
//my code
```

Ok, the function returned the string before last occurrence

```
$text = 'This is a test to test code';
echo strrchr($text, 'test');
//t code
```

But in this case, why the function is returning "t code", instead "test code"?

Thanks

Comment: From the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php), `If needle contains more than one character, only the first is used.` In your first case, that letter is `m`, in the second case, it's `t`

Comment: @MarkBaker, that really needs to be an answer rather than a comment , perhaps with a source linked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)**:

> needle
>
> If needle contains more than one character, **only the first is used**. This behavior is different
> from that of strstr().

---

So your **first example** is the exact same as:

```
$text = 'This is my code';
echo strrchr($text, 'm');
```

**RESULT**

```
'This is my code'
         ^
        'my code'
```

---

Your **second example** is the exact same as:

```
$text = 'This is a test to test code';
echo strrchr($text, 't');
```

**RESULT**

```
'This is a test to test code'
                      ^
                     't code'
```

---

This function I made does what you were expecting:

```
/**
 * Give the last occurrence of a string and everything that follows it
 * in another string
 * @param  String $needle   String to find
 * @param  String $haystack Subject
 * @return String           String|empty string
 */
function strrchrExtend($needle, $haystack)
{
    if (preg_match('/(('.$needle.')(?:.(?!\2))*)$/', $haystack, $matches))
        return $matches[0];
    return '';
}
```

The regex it uses can be tested here: **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oJ2sC7/1)**

**example**:

```
echo strrchrExtend('test', 'This is a test to test code');
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
test code
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple! Because it finds the last occurrence of a **character** in a string. Not a word.

It just finds the last occurrence character and then it will `echo` the rest of the string from that position.

---

**In your first example:**

```
$text = 'This is my code';
echo strrchr($text, 'my');
```

It finds the last `m` and then prints the reset included `m` itself: `my code`

**In your second example:**

```
$text = 'This is a test to test code';
echo strrchr($text, 'test');
```

It finds the last `t` and like the last example prints the rest: `test code`

[More info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)

Answer (score 0):

From PHP doc :

haystack
The string to search in

needle
If needle contains more than one character, **only the first is used**. This behavior is different from that of strstr().

In your example, only the first character of your needle (t) will be used